# Can I put letters instead of some numbers as ticks in a ValueAxis?

Tags: jfreechart

this is my program:

[Program before](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygq1so48ma9igj0/imagen1.png)

and I want it to look like this:

[Program after](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tonq38voxrzjg42/imagen2.png)

is this possible to add letters at some specific points in the ValueAxis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your links are not working, you may get a better responce using Imager and adding some example code or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

In the meantime is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917167/jfreechart-customize-ticket-labels/13918735#13918735) what you are trying to do