# Is it possible to have two (X and Y) CategoryAxes in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating a correlation matrix in JFreeChart. I'm nearly done except that both axes have number values (i: say 1 to 20). I use DefaultXYZDataset and a customized BlockRenderer with a overridden PaintScale Class. The value z itself is represented by the colour of a filled rectangle at the positions (x,y) in ([1 to 20], [1 to 20]).

Is it possible to replace the axis labels on X and Y by a String e.g. names[i]? To achieve this, have I to change the NumberAxes into CategoryAxes? Both axes needed to be categorical since I need coordinates like ("ParameterA", "ParameterB"). I guess i would need a special renderer then and the whole code had to be modified. On first sight this isn't even possible. I didn't found a suitable Dataset for that task.

Or could i simply change some kind of tick label format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839170/230513), is a `NumberAxis` and might be a suitable choice.

[image]

Comment: Yes. How could I miss this one. I tried it and it worked at once. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome; kudos to @GrahamA for the [illustration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12839170/230513).