# Y tags in XYSeriesCollection (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an XY chart where I want to represent X values along some dates. The creation of the dataset is simple:

```
XYSeries serie = new XYSeries("valor");
for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
    serie.add(i,lista.get(i).getValue());

}
dataset.addSeries(serie);
```

where serie.add uses as arguments (y.value, x.value). I am representing the x value along time, but it appears as just the index of the arraylist (obvious, I use i as the first parameter). My question is, how could I show dates (or Strings) as the Y values?
I know that this possible to be done with a BarChart, for instance:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataSet.addValue(51, "series", "Colonel Forbin");
        dataSet.addValue(92, "series", "The Lizards");
```

Something like this is what I need to do, hope you could help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513), if the range values in your series represent milliseconds from the Java [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)), a `DateAxis` should display the values correctly.

```
NumberAxis domain = new NumberAxis("X");
DateAxis range = new DateAxis("Y");
domain.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
XYItemRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, domain, range, renderer);
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
    "Title", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);
```

Addendum: *I just want to set … tags that change dynamically.*

It looks like you want `SymbolAxis`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336050/230513).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but I have been searching about this classes and I havent found a solution for my case. My problem is, I have an ArrayList of objects, lets say "object" with 2 fields: float "value" and String "date". I represent "value" in the chart and in the Y axis I want to see "date" of each object (rigth now I represent just i). The dates arent consecutive but they re sorted, like, there are no weekends or some holidays. Basically I need to asociate a String to each value. Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Use a `DateAxis`, as shown in the example cited above; edit your question to clarify your intent and include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Comment: Im sorry if I havent explained myself properly yet, but how can I assign a label to each value with the DateAxis? I ve looked though the methods but I havent found anything. I just want to set a vector or an arraylist to the tags, that change dynamically. Thanks

Comment: Excellent! Sorry for the confusion; answer updated to reflect a clearer understanding.