# JFreeChart XYSeries as Strings

Tags: java, jfreechart, series

im working with jfreechart and try to make a XYLineChart which is working very well.

My problem is, that the y label are double values and i need strings.

My Code:

```
DefaultXYDataset result = new DefaultXYDataset();

XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Words");
series1.add(0, 0.3);
series1.add(1, 0.5);
series1.add(2, 0.6);
series1.add(3, 0.3);
series1.add(4, 0.2);
series1.add(5, 1);                
result.addSeries(getTitle(), series1.toArray());
```

I want something like:

```
XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Words");
series1.add("word 1", 0.3);
series1.add("word 2", 0.5);
...
```

The updated code using Symbol-Axis:

```
private void test2() {
    XYDataset dataset = createDataset2();

    JFreeChart chart = createChart2(dataset, "NN");

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 250));

    panel_visualize.add(chartPanel);   
}


private  DefaultXYDataset createDataset2() 
{
    DefaultXYDataset result = new DefaultXYDataset();

    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Words");    

    series1.add(0.3, 0);
    series1.add(0.5, 1);
    series1.add(0.6, 2);
    series1.add(0.3, 3);
    series1.add(0.2, 4);    

    result.addSeries(getTitle(), series1.toArray());

    return result;  
}


private JFreeChart createChart2(XYDataset dataset, String title) 
{    

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title,          // chart title
        "Words", 
        "Activation", 
        dataset,                // data
        PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 
        true,                   // include legend
        true,
        false);


    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);


    String[] grade =  new String[5];
    grade[0] = "Temp 0";
    grade[1] = "Temp 1";
    grade[2] = "Temp 2";
    grade[3] = "Temp 3";
    grade[4] = "Temp 4";
    SymbolAxis rangeAxis = new SymbolAxis("Words", grade);

    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
    rangeAxis.setRange(0,grade.length);
    plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);

    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `SymbolAxis`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12839170/230513).

Comment: Thx for the answer. Is it possible to label the y-Axes with Strings

Comment: It depends on how you create the chart. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: update: using plot.setDomainAxis(rangeAxis); solves my problem

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
plot.setDomainAxis(rangeAxis);
```

solves my problem.

Thanks to trashgod for the help.