# display duplicate name into Line chart from JFreechart API

Tags: charts, jfreechart, linechart

My line chart have Y-axis numeric and X-axis String, So how can display duplicate name into X-asix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFreeChart XYSeries as Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688496/jfreechart-xyseries-as-strings). `SymbolAxis` supports duplicate values.

Comment: Can you give one example.

Comment: There's one if you click the link!