# Customize x axis with JfreeChart XYLineChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, axis, dendrogram

I'm displaying the results of a clustering operation on a `XYLineChart` using `JFreeChart`. For now the plot I get is this one:

[image]

I need to change the x axis in order to get this display:

[image]

So basically I first need to get rid of the tick and numbers (this I already searched and found a way to manage how to do it). The problem for me is to add my own custom String values on the x axis AND to have these positionned at specific position. I already have an arraylist with the Strings and another one with the position values, no need to calculate them, i just want to know how to use them with the plot.

Thank you in advance and, as usual, please tell me if my explanation needs to be clarified.

Comment: Try `SymbolAxis`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12835369/230513).

Answer (score 0):

in order to change the content of the display, you need to change your query to have the output you like to see.
to change the position you may need to use something like:
categoryPlot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);

you need to show some of your code so that you can get the proper advice